# Using AWK to search row and replace to the specific values from another row

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I want to replace the '1' from the first row with the value given in the second row. Here is the input dataset:

```
0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1
65,70,75,80,85,85,90
```

Desired output:

```
0,0,65,70,0,0,75,80,0,85,0,85,0,90
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Like this (any `awk`):

```
$ tac file | awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    NR==1{split($0, a, FS);next}
    NR==2{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i == 1) $i=a[++c]}
    1 # aka print
'
```

Replace `tac file` by `tail -r file` on `*BSD`

### Output

```
0,0,65,70,0,0,75,80,0,85,0,85,0,90
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: +1 and also please correct the header and remove awk requirement.

Comment: I don't get what you mean both for headers and awk requirement

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/([^,]*)1\>(,?[^\n]*\n)([0-9]+)(,|\n)/\1\3\2/;ta' input_file
0,0,65,70,0,0,75,80,0,85,0,85,0,90
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked

Comment: That would fail if one of the numbers on the 2nd line contained 1, e.g. try changing `70` to `15` or `21`.

Answer (score 0):

I like @GillesQuenot's answer, but here's an alternative using perl that doesn't need `tac` or `tail -r`.

Instead, it uses three arrays - one for the first input line (`@l`), one for the second line (`@a`), and the third for output (`@o)`.  It does the printing in the END block:

```
$ perl -F, -le '
    if ($.==1) { @l = @F };
    if ($.==2) { @a = @F };
    END {
      foreach $i (0..$#l) {
        push @o, $l[$i] == 1 ? $a[$c++] : $l[$i]
      };
      print join("," , @o)
    }' input.txt
0,0,65,70,0,0,75,80,0,85,0,85,0,90
```

BTW, perl's `-F` option automatically enables perl's `-a` (auto-split to an array called @F) and `-n` (iterate over input like `sed -n` or `awk`) options. `-l` enables automatic handling of line-ending chars (e.g. newlines).

You could do something similar with awk, but you'd probably have to write a `join()` function (which is built-in to perl).